# Software to host multiple camera images at once

Tags: video, streaming

We are looking to set-up a page of multiple camera outputs on the same website and make it available to multiple people via the web. Kind of like a security or traffic camera screen with multiple cameras always in view. It is even fine if it's just still images getting updated every 10 seconds or so. The main requirement is that it should take zero set-up for the users, nothing to install, no long loading times, etc. Ideally just a webpage showing the images of all cameras.

I am sure there must be existing solutions, that we can just plugin into, something in the security or traffic space. But I can't find anything online, I think part of the problem is also that I don't know what terms to search for. Does anyone have any hints for me?

Answer (score 1):

Since the advent of HTML5 you can do this with a standard webpage that contains multiple  elements, with no special software required. This will embed a video in a page that any modern browser can see.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

A primer on the HTML5 video element [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Since you're streaming the video it's a little more complex, you need to use the [media source extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API). If you want to look at how streaming works, there's a good guide [here](https://medium.com/canal-tech/how-video-streaming-works-on-the-web-an-introduction-7919739f7e1)